# CakePHP 2.0 / Stripe Payment Integration

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, stripe-payments

I'm new-ish to Cake. I'm building a site in 2.1 and trying to implement the Stripe payment gateway.

I've found a couple plugins/components but their documentation isn't really clear for me.

Here's one: https://github.com/jeremyharris/stripe/blob/master/README.md

I've added the folder to my plugins folder, loaded the plugin via bootstrap.php, configured the database.php file, and created a new model named Authorize.php with the code in the Readme.

I'm just stuck now, not sure what to do. I added a very basic form to a test page but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Here's my testpayment.ctp in my Pages controller:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Authorize');
echo $this->Form->input('Card Number');
echo $this->Form->input('Expiration');
echo $this->Form->input('CCV');
echo $this->Form->end('Send');
```

Any help is VERY appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also struggled while trying the above Plugin. I had it setup nice and it kept throwing whole sorts of warnings and errors. One thing you need to understand is the Stripe payment flow. I was lucky to find [this simple plugin](https://github.com/chronon/CakePHP-StripeComponent-Plugin) which took me less than half an hour to have Stripe working. If you are still newish to Cake, read through the official docs, both for [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) and [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that one a shot.

Comment: Yes it's definitely easier and simpler plugin

Comment: Can i also subscribe customers with it? I didn't see any explanation for it in docs.

Answer (score 4):

None of the existing components were good enough for me, so I just finished my component, which contains all the methods

https://github.com/hashmode/CakePHP-Stripe-Component-Full

The usage is very simple, if you read the Stripe docs, for example lets consider adding credit card: According to [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_card), we need the customer's id and and the card data as an array or as a token. So, the usage will be

```
$customerId = 'cus_asdfasdfasdf';
$cardData = array('number' => '1111111111111', 'exp_month' => '10',
    'exp_year' => 2022, 'cvc' => 123);
$response = $this->Stripe->createCard($customerId, $cardData);
```

The same logic is used for the rest of the methods.